# MediaElement.js error in IE8

Tags: jquery-plugins, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

I'm looking to use mediaelement.js to show some HTML5 audio players on a page. Everything seems to be working great in Chrome/FF, but not in IE8.

http://future.thefutureforward.com/~orion/multimedia.html

The flash fallback .swf file is in the same folder as my mediaelement-and-player.min.js, so that's not the issue. I've tried script tags in the  (where they are now) and before the , but that doesn't help.

Any thoughts as to why IE isn't functioning here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This bug is now solved in the latest version of mediaelement-and-player.min.js. Make sure you have version 2.9.3 installed.

Full details discussed in this github issue:
https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/pull/598